# where does the javascript function reside and what is the value

Tags: javascript

```
var test = (function(){ 

    this.message = function(){
        alert('hi');
    };
})();
```

I have 2 questions

1. where does the above function go? does it go to the dom with class name test?
2. how to create a new object every time and call the function.

what i want to do is to create a class like data structure, create objects using modular javascript.
i have tried the above code, however, i feel i get the message function in the window object rather that the entire class.

Comment: Hmmm "does it go to the dom with class name test?" what makes you think so? :)

Comment: `message` will be added to the global object (`window`), since you refer to `this` in a self-invocating anonymous function without using `bind()`,  `call()` or `apply()`. That code is quite a complicated design, could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve with it?

Comment: You just wrote plain javascript...  Why are you refering to DOM?

Comment: Not sure where you have seen that code, but `test` will be `undefined`  and `this`in the function will be the _global_  object (in case of the browser it will be `window`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite your code into the following rough equivalent:

```
var test;

function foobar()
{
  this.message = function() {
    alert('hi');
  }
}

foobar();
```

*The `foobar` function represents the anonymous function that gets immediately invoked.*

Inside the function, `this` will reference `window` (in a browser), so effectively it adds the `message` function to `window`, achieving the following:

```
window.message = function() {
  alert('hi');
};
```

However, if you wish to create objects you need to use `new`, e.g.:

```
function test()
{
  this.message = function() {
    alert('hi');
  };
}

var x = new test();
x.message(); // alerts hi
```

As mentioned by NULL in the comments, it's recommended to use Title Casing when your function is to be used with `new`, i.e. `function Test() { ... }`.

Comment: This is actually a really good answer, But Please Always Make Classes With Uppercase First Word, eg <--

Comment: thanks, actually i am new to javascript and i wanted to know this very simple understaning. thanks every one